# Changing target date of work items in Azure Devops Delivery Plans

Tags: azure-devops

In my delivery plan in ADO I can change the start date of any teams work item (some are user stories others are epics) by dragging the start of the work item to a different date. However I can not set a custom target date of any work item of any team this way. The target date is always snapped to match an end date of the iteration.

I have added the teams and I see their iterations associated with them.  I can also add work items and have them displayed as expected.

I've seen the docs that state don't specify an iteration path and a target date however you have to set an iteration path first for the work item to appear in the delivery plan.  I should be able to then override this by setting a target date by dragging the work item.

I'm guessing I've configured something wrong because I've been able to do this in the past, but I've reviewed the team, project and iterations setups and they all seem to be correct. I've also reviewed the delivery plans docs from ADO and I dont see anything Im missing here.

Any ideas of what I might be missing I would be grateful